# Gactions cli Not Pulling Actions.yaml

Tags: actions-on-google

From what I'm reading in https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions/guide to get a local copy of my Gactions Project I should be able to use

`gactions pull --project-id my-project-id`

My project has 1 action

[image: 1 Action]

Looking at the output from the pull and theres no actions.yaml there's only

- manifest.yaml
- settings/settings.yaml
- settings/en/settings.yaml

How do I get gactions to pull the entire definition actions.yaml and all?

Comment: Gactions Version 3.1.0+337599905

Comment: And you're defining the project in Dialogflow?

Comment: Yes Dialogflow is the fullfillment tool its all setup and working but it was setup using the Actions Console and DialogFlow now I'm trying to pull a copy of the config but I only get part. If I change anything in that part and try a push it complains thats theres no actions.yaml

Comment: Ah. Gactions does not support getting an actions.yaml for any Dialogflow project.

Comment: ouch! well maybe some day  things will change and someone will have an easy answer and flame me for asking such a simple question :D ... thanks.